# Why VoIP RTP has multiple ports instead of single?

Tags: security, voip, rtp

In VoIP we have `SIP` and `RTP` protocol and SIP works on 5060 but while RTP works on big range like `10000 to 20000` whatever you define in config.

Just wonder why RTP doesn't work like DNS/HTTP just single to many, i mean server side it listen on single port and clients connect to specific single port, in that case security wise it will be much easies.

Answer (score 1):

I can see 3 reasons why RTP was invented to use different ports:

1. packet size: if there would be only one port, then there should be extra information in each packet about the channel number, which increases the payload size a bit
2. performance: using multiple ports we can avoid an extra lookup for channel number which should be performed at each packet arrival otherwise
3. ease of usage: for developers it is easier to write the media stack using multiple ports

However there are special modified SIP software which can work this way (port multiplexing)

Answer (score 0):

SIP does not have to be assigned to 5060 port, it can use dynamic port (e.g. softphone registering to server and receiving calls through proxy - other peers do not need to know its port).

Technically I don't see why both SIP and RTP couldn't use single (same) port, at least with single call phone. There might be some issues with multiple calls though as separate local ports might be only way to differentiate incoming streams sometimes (e.g. multiple streams/calls from same host and source port advertised in SDP different than assigned by router/NAT).

Application you have described probably changes RTP/RTCP port(s) each call, opening new socket(s) each time. It significantly reduces chance that current stream (call) would be disturbed by RTP packets from previous call if wasn't finalized in a proper way (e.g. transaction timeout for BYE due to network problems or crash + restart).

Port range can be probably reduced without bigger problems (to number of simultaneous calls or number of calls x2 because of RTCP), although there is risk that ports from specified range would be in use by another application.